# RTL support for Angular Tree Control

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to make [Angular Tree Control](https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control) work with RTL language in IE 9+. [Here is what I have so far](https://github.com/olakara/AngularTreePOC)!

These overridden CSS works fine for all browers except IE:

```
treecontrol li {

  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

treecontrol.tree-classic li.tree-expanded i {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

treecontrol.tree-classic li.tree-collapsed i {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

treecontrol.tree-classic li.tree-leaf i {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
```

But I have issues with IE. In IE, I currently have this:

[image: IE Result]

But in Chrome and Firefox, I have:

[image: IN Chrome]

What I am trying to achieve is remove the empty space between the icon and text. I have tried playing with padding but that doesn't seems to be the solution.

Any insights to fix this??

Comment: Maybe there are some default ie values to overwrite? Just think about related css properties and test it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an online demo.

Comment: Maybe.. I am not able to figure out what it is and how to fix it.. I was able to reach this far but that minor issue has been quite a pain!!

Comment: @HashemQolami ya.. Its in progress..

Comment: Here is a similar library on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j1xor84w/